# AppsFlyer’s SDK receipt validation fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation, appsflyer-ios-sdk

Trying to do in‐app purchase server receipt validation using AppsFlyer’s SDK. Called the `validateAndTrackInAppPurchase` method inside the SKStoreKit’s `completeTransaction:` callback. However it fails and always returns following response.

```
{
    environment = Sandbox;

    status = 21004;

}
```

`21004` response says `The shared secret you provided does not match the shared secret on file for your account.`

But I don't have much idea about this `shared secret`

```
[[AppsFlyerTracker sharedTracker] validateAndTrackInAppPurchase:productId price:priceString
                                                           currency:@"USD"
                                                      transactionId:transaction.transactionIdentifier
                                               additionalParameters:@{@"test": @"val" , @"test1" : @"val 1"}
                                                            success:^(NSDictionary *result){
                                                                NSLog(@"Purchase succeeded And verified!!! response: %@", result[@"receipt"]);
                                                            } failure:^(NSError *error, id response) {
                                                                NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
                                                                if([response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                                                                    if([response[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"in_app_arr_empty"]){
                                                                        // retry with 'SKReceiptRefreshRequest' because
                                                                        // Apple has returned an empty response
                                                                        // <YOUR CODE HERE>
                                                                    }

                                                                } else {
                                                                    //handle other errors
                                                                    return;
                                                                }
                                                            }];
```

Answer (score 3):

As you know `Auto-Renewable Subscription` demands `App-Specific Shared Secret`,

See `appstoreconnect.apple.com` -> `My Apps` -> `Features` tab -> `In-App Purchases` -> `Auto-Renewable Subscription` Item section:

[image]

Shared secret looks like: `e21e428f20db4d6d90c9192b9b7b2a75`

1) `21004` means you try to test Auto-Renewable Subscription and AppsFlyer doesn't have the Shared Secret key.

Please contact the support@appsflyer.com to get more details.

---

What happens if you do not use `Auto-Renewable Subscription` but still get this error: `21004`:

Apple has some issues with testing in sandbox mode. Try to create a new tester account and do your test again. In the past, once you used account `A` for testing `Auto-Renewable Subscription`, all other attempts to test other types of purchase such Consumable, Non-Consumable, Non-Renewing Subscription with account `A` - Apple returns the same error `21004`.

Hope it can help you,

Comment: Thanks for your response. However appsflyer support team says they cannot add a secret key for iOS automatic subscription renewal. Does appsflyer actually provide the receipt validation for iOS automatic subscription?